# Join two ;-delimited list columns, possibly null, in Python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi Python Noob question:

- I have a dataframe with two columns `col1,col2` that contain ';'-delimited lists. Some of the values in each of the columns are null.
- I want to combine them into a single list in a new column `col3`
- However, in the case of null values I just want the new field to contain the value of the existing not-null field.

In SQL I can accomplish this with:

```
  SELECT  
  CASE 
  WHEN col1 is not null and col2 is not null THEN col1+';'+col2 
  WHEN col1 is not null and col2 is null THEN col_a
  WHEN col1 is null and col2 is not null THEN col_b end as col3
  FROM TBL
```

What's the best way to do this with python? I've tried a few different approaches based on similar questions but I keep getting errors.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'col1': ['a;b;c;', 'd;e', np.nan, np.nan, 'g'],
        'col2': ['a' , np.nan , 'b;c', np.nan , np.nan]
     })

df.loc[ ( df['col1'].notnull & df['col2'].notnull) , 'col3'] = df['col1'].fillna('') +';'+ df['col2'].fillna('')


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-89fd68e80fd1> in <module>
----> 1 df.loc[ (df['col1'].notnull & df['col2'].notnull) , 'col3'] = df['col1'].fillna('') +';'+ df['col2'].fillna('')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'method' and 'method'
```

Comment: `df['col1'].notnull()`. You missed the brackets

Comment: Probably you mean `notnull()`

Comment: I assume you should be using `and` here, not `&`.

Comment: You do not necessarily have to check for `notnull()`

Comment: @JohnGordon no, they shouldn't, they are pandas/numpy objects which use the bitwise operators to mean element by element and/or

Comment: I expected it was something simple I was missing. Thanks !

Comment: It's best not to use SQL terminology like 'case statement', just describe in words what transformations you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'].fillna('')+df['col2'].fillna('')

    col1    col2    col3
0   a;b;c;  a       a;b;c;a
1   d;e              d;e
2           b;c      b;c
3           
4     g               g
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

applying the comments about the missing () I used

```
df.loc[ ( df['col1'].notnull() & df['col2'].notnull()) , 'col3'] = df['col1'].fillna('') +';'+ df['col2'].fillna('')
df.loc[ ( df['col1'].notnull() & df['col2'].isnull()) , 'col3'] = df['col1']
df.loc[ ( df['col1'].isnull() & df['col2'].notnull()) , 'col3'] = df['col2']
```

That got me what I was after. 
Thanks all for your help.